# Trouble installing tidyverse in R

Tags: r, package, tidyverse

I'm having trouble installing tidyverse in R. When installing the package, the installation starts but stops after a while and nothing happens. It seems like it's still in "installation mode" since I cannot to anything else (when I try to create a variable, it doesn't show up in the global environment/nothing happens).

What am I doing wrong? 
[image: This is what the console looks like when the installation stops]

Answer (score 1):

It must be an internet connection error. Trying installing it in this way:

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyverse")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same issue using this method as well. :(

Comment: If you can, use a different proxy using available apps. It works for me everytime.